# why is my variable increasing exponentially?

Tags: java, swing

I have a piece of code that moves a rectangle whenever i press a button.  it it set up so that the x or y coordinate decreases or increases by 1 pixel each time the key is pressed.  however, i am noticing that if i press the same key more than once in a row, the 1 pixel compounds itself somehow , stacks may be a better word, and increases exponentially.  is there anything in the code that you can see why it would do this?

```
public class drawingComponent extends JComponent implements KeyListener
{

    Rectangle   hello   = new Rectangle(300, 100, 50, 50);

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setColor(new Color(255, 25, 0));
        g2.setFont(new Font("monospace", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 30));
        g2.drawString("nothing yet", 300, 320);
        g2.fill(hello);
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
        addKeyListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e)
    {

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W)
        {
            hello.y = hello.y - 1;
            hello.setLocation(hello.x, hello.y);
            repaint();
            System.out.println(hello.y);
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S)
        {
            hello.y = hello.y + 1;
            hello.setLocation(hello.x, hello.y);
            repaint();

        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A)
        {
            hello.x = hello.x - 1;
            hello.setLocation(hello.x, hello.y);
            repaint();

        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D)
        {
            hello.x = hello.x + 1;
            hello.setLocation(hello.x, hello.y);
            repaint();

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased (KeyEvent e)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped (KeyEvent e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: "Exponentially" is not a synonym for "quickly".

Comment: Did you format your code by having your cat/dog walk across your keyboard? Whilst the effort to make the code as obfuscated as possible is evident, I would suggest that you use more conventional formatting techniques.

Comment: Don't change the state of your component from within the `paint` methods, paint is for painting the state, nothing else. Don't use `KeyListener`, this way you can avoid all the stupid focus issues, use the key bindings API instead.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Comment: If you had followed the advice provided to you [earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831196/request-focus-for-keylistener-not-sure-if-i-have-focus-or-not), you wouldn't have this problem...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're adding your `KeyListener` on each repaint of your component:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    //..
    addKeyListener(this); // adds another KeyListener
}
```

And every call of `repaint();` adds another `KeyListener` that will do his job, if `keyPressed` is called. That means, you have `one` listener first, then `two`, then `four`, then `sixteen` and so on.

Don't do that. Add your listener once in the constructor or so.

The constructor can look like this:

```
public drawingComponent() {
    // init other stuff
    addKeyListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Or just use key bindings instead :P

Comment: +1 but I agree with @MadProgrammer (+1 to his answer). Key Bindings are a much better solution in this situation as was discussed in [wilkers previous thread on this subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831196/request-focus-for-keylistener-not-sure-if-i-have-focus-or-not).

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to overcome an inherent issue with an API by using hacks and workarounds which may or may not work on other systems or platforms.

Do not change the state of a component from within a `paint` method, painting should paint the current state, nothing else.  By requesting focus within the paint method, you could be triggering another repaint request to be made, resulting in a vicious cycle which will consume your CPU cycles.

The core problem is (as highlighted by Tom), you're adding ANOTHER `KeyListener` everytime `paint` is called.  Painting will occur, a lot, and usually without your knowledge or request.

Instead of fighting this problem, you should use the API which was designed to fix it, the key bindings API.  This API will allow you to define the level of focus required to trigger the key events, the following example mimics the default behaviour of the `KeyListener` (as I don't know your other requirements), but has an option to allow the component to become focusable.

Some tips...

- Always caller `super.paintComponent` before doing custom painting, this is easy to forget and can result in some seriously weird graphics glitches.
- There's no need for `paintComponent` to be `public`, you never want anyone to ever call it.
- You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

As a simple example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new DrawingComponent());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class DrawingComponent extends JComponent {

        Rectangle hello = new Rectangle(300, 100, 50, 50);

        public DrawingComponent() {
            setFocusable(true);
            InputMap im = getInputMap();

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0), "Move.up");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0), "Move.down");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0), "Move.left");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0), "Move.right");

            ActionMap am = getActionMap();
            am.put("Move.up", new DeltaAction(0, -1));
            am.put("Move.down", new DeltaAction(0, 1));
            am.put("Move.left", new DeltaAction(-1, 0));
            am.put("Move.right", new DeltaAction(1, 0));

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    requestFocusInWindow();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setColor(new Color(255, 25, 0));
            g2.setFont(new Font("monospace", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 30));
            g2.drawString("nothing yet", 300, 320);
            g2.fill(hello);
        }

        public class DeltaAction extends AbstractAction {

            private int xDelta;
            private int yDelta;

            public DeltaAction(int xDelta, int yDelta) {
                this.xDelta = xDelta;
                this.yDelta = yDelta;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                hello.x += xDelta;
                hello.y += yDelta;
                repaint();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

*"But why should I use the key bindings API"* I hear you asking?  Apart from providing you more flexibility and configurability (including setting the level of focus required to trigger the events, you could also change the keys which trigger the events more easily and or have a multiple set of keys - think the arrow keys as well), it can be used with other parts of the Swing API, including buttons.

A single `Action` can be applied to `JMenuItem`s, `JButton`s and key bindings, no extra coding required...

See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Comment: thanks for the detailed and professional response sir.